# rs is always true even when table employee is not present in servlet Database

Tags: java, mysql, database, jakarta-ee

rs is always true even when table employee is not present in servlet Database, want to create table only when table is not present in database
and what will `SELECT count(*)FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE(TABLE_SCHEMA = 'servlet') AND (TABLE_NAME = 'employee')"` 
will return when executed with PreparedStement and result stored in resultSet when table is not there and when table is there for both the cases

```
public class Table {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
Connection con=null;
PreparedStatement pstmt=null;
PreparedStatement pstmt1=null;
PreparedStatement pstmt2=null;
ResultSet rs=null;
String qry="SELECT count(*)FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE(TABLE_SCHEMA = 'servlet') AND (TABLE_NAME = 'employee')";
String qry1="CREATE TABLE servlet.Employee (" +
            " ID INT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, " +
            " NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, " + 
            " Department varchar(20) NOT NULL, " + 
            " Salary DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL, " + 
            " PRIMARY KEY (ID))";
String qry2="insert into servlet.Employee values(?,?,?,?)";

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306?user=root&password=passworD");
pstmt=con.prepareStatement(qry);
rs=pstmt.executeQuery();
System.out.println(rs.next());
    if(true==!rs.next()){
    pstmt1=con.prepareStatement(qry1);
    pstmt1.executeUpdate();
    pstmt2=con.prepareStatement(qry2);
    pstmt2.setInt(1,id);
    pstmt2.setString(2, name);
    pstmt2.setString(3, dept);
    pstmt2.setDouble(4, salary);
    pstmt2.executeUpdate();
    }
    else{

    pstmt2=con.prepareStatement(qry2);
    pstmt2.setInt(1,id);
    pstmt2.setString(2, name);
    pstmt2.setString(3, dept);
    pstmt2.setDouble(4, salary);
    pstmt2.executeUpdate();
    }
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the table exists the value will be `1` else will be `0`. So a record always exists. As the documentation says:

> ResultSet.next: Moves the cursor forward one row. Returns true if the cursor is now positioned on a row and false if the cursor is positioned after the last row.

rs.next will always return true since there it position the cursor on the first record in your case. You need to process the logic based on the value of `count(*)`. You do not need the else clause since you are not doing something vary different.

```
if(rs.next())
  int count = rs.getInt(1);
  if (count == 0) {
    pstmt1=con.prepareStatement(qry1);
    pstmt1.executeUpdate();
  }
  pstmt2=con.prepareStatement(qry2);
  pstmt2.setInt(1,id);
  pstmt2.setString(2, name);
  pstmt2.setString(3, dept);
  pstmt2.setDouble(4, salary);
  pstmt2.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: Thank you but why rs is always true

Comment: yes my problem has been solved but i can't understand what is wrong in the logic applied by me as (!rs.next()) is true when table not present and it should only work when table not present else the remaining code should  work as corrected by you @randominstanceoflivingthing

Comment: Please re-read my answer about the next method to understand the problem with your logic.